# how to get am/pm using simple date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I want to get 12 hour clock time from milliseconds.I tried as follows

```
public class GetTimeFormat{
    static SimpleDateFormat format; 
    public static String convertDate(String dateformat,Long date){
        format = new SimpleDateFormat(dateformat);
        String formattedDate = format.format(date);
        return formattedDate;
    }
    
public static void main(String args[])
{
    
    long cal=1386059340010l;
    
    String dateString=convertDate("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss a", cal);
    System.out.println(dateString);

}
}
```

The corresponding date for the above milliseconds is `Tue Dec 03 13:59:00 IST 2013`

So I thought I will get formatted date as `Dec 03,2013 1:59:00 PM`

but instead I am getting `Dec 03,2013 13:59:00 PM`

there is no need for am/pm in 24 hour clock and in 12 hour clock am/pm is required

But In my way I am getting time in 24 hour format + PM.

Can Any body tell me whats the mistake here?

Another question is why in [ideone](https://ideone.com/HsbFu6) its showing `Dec 03,2013 08:29:00 AM`
Not only in ideone but I have checked many online compilers and every where its showing the same but in local machine time is different(13:59)

Comment: 10 seconds of looking into [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) showed in the Examples section: `"h:mm a" -> 12:08 PM`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lowercase `h` in your format pattern:

```
String dateString = convertDate("MMM dd,yyyy h:mm:ss a", cal);
```

You can see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for a full reference of format patterns, including an example that covers this specific case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,can you please answer why it does not work in ideone(the 2nd part of my question)

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of differing [`TimeZone`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)? - If you don't explicitly specify a TimeZone to use, the result is just displayed according to the default timezone as configured for the *machine the code is running on*.